# how to run apk file in android

Tags: android-emulator

I try to run apk file in android, i follow these steps 
1. First get the Android SDK and unzip it somewhere on your hard drive 
2. Add SDK_ROOT to your system variables pointing to /tools folder under the sdk 
3. Run the emulator 
4. Copy the apk file to /tools folder 
5. Change directory to /tools and run from commandline $adb install your_application.apk 6. Now check applications list in the emulator and you should see the new application installed and ready.

but i get this type of error : 
" [2011-01-11 17:02:15 - Logcat]device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:284)
 at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:527) "

can you help me any one.... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start first the emulator. Navigate to the $SDK_ROOT/tools directory and execute the file 'emulator.exe'. Wait couple of minutes until it loads. Now run :

```
$adb install your_application.apk
```

If all went without errors then you should be seeing your newly installed APK on the emulator.